# Creating/Deleting folders using c++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, directory

Need some help about creating/deleting/opening directories using c++. I searched the Internet for it but could not find a good answer.

This is for my homework that a part of it involve creating and deleting folders and surfing in them and I'm  using g++ compiler in Linux to compile it.

I've read about a library called `direct.h` and I don't think its a c++ library and has to be added to include libraries.

How can I create/delete/open a folder using c++ using the standard library?

Comment: There is no actual question here.  [What have you tried](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/142865)?

Comment: How can i create/delete/open a folder using c++?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  And what do you mean "open a folder?"  Do you need to enumerate the content of that folder?  Create a file within it?  Specifics, specifics...

Comment: the program get command line by line with their input like Linux terminal and there is a command (add proj_name) that says create a project and what it does is it creates a folder for user to add his/her project files to it

Comment: OK, much better.  So you just need to create a new directory if it doesn't exist.  `mkdir` will do what you need.  See @jesse's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use boost, there's [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) which has the function [`create_directory`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#create_directories) just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mkdir in sys/stat.h http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mkdir.html

Comment: is it available in all versions of g++ compiler? cause I have to give them my code and they will compile it with g++

Answer (score 1):

On linux you can use functions mkdir() and rmdir(). Check the man page: [mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir), [rmdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rmdir).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Deleting a file:
http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/

Opening/creating a file:
http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

Yes, these are C functions, but luckily C functions work in C++.

For creating a directory, try mkdir. You can read about it in man pages:
man 2 mkdir

Good luck!